# Adding an existing entity to a child collection of a many-to-many relationship

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have to entities that represent a `Message` and a `Topic`.
A `Message` can have many `Topic`, and a `Topic` can belong to many `Message`

```
public class Message
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Message> Topics { get; set; }
}

public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Message> Messages { get; set; }
}
```

In my application, we first save `Topic` (early on in the application, sometimes seed data etc...)

Later, I need to save a new `Message` - adding an already existing `Topic` to the child collection;

```
var message = new Message();
message.Text = "Hello";
//this topic already exists in the database
message.Topics.Add(new Topic{Id = 6, Value = "val"}); 
dbContext.Messages.Add(message);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

What happens is:

- `Message` is saved
- *New* topic is created (with Value of "val")
- ID of *new* topic is saved in MessageTopics mapping table against the newly created `Message` ID

What I want to happen is

- `Message` is saved
- ID of supplied topic (6 in this case) is saved in MessageTopics table against the newly created `Message` ID

Comment: Topic needs to be a reference created by DbContext, so first get the topic from `context.Topics` then add that reference to the `message.Topics` That is how the context change tracking works

Comment: I personally try to steer clear of those types of entity framework mappings, I always create the join tables. That way you don't have to worry about the object reference coming from the DbContext and other nuances

Comment: that works... but now i'm doing another round-trip to the db to retrieve the topic (again) - can I load it without doing effectively a SinlgeOrDefault on it?

Comment: A point is that are sure this topic exists in the first place, small round trip to the db to get this isn't going to be expensive....

Comment: Maybe this may help http://sanderstechnology.com/2013/solving-the-detached-many-to-many-problem-with-the-entity-framework/12505/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First option

If everything is mapped correctly then the only thing you need to do is to hold *reference to topic* and set its state to `Unchanged`:

```
// This topic already exists in the database.
// No need to set value.
var topic = new Topic{ Id = 6 };
var message = new Message();
message.Text = "Hello"; 
message.Topics.Add(topic); 
dbContext.Messages.Add(message);

// Set state of topic to Unchanged
dbContext.Entry(topic).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

### Second option.

Just get topic from database if there is not too much data.

```
// Get topic from source
var topic = dbContext.Topics.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == 6);
var message = new Message();
message.Text = "Hello";
message.Topics.Add(topic); 
dbContext.Messages.Add(message);
dbContext.SaveChanges();
```